# Antd form initial value not updating after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a table showing school name and its fee or rates. There is button in table which opens a drawer containing this component or form.There is a button in table which toggles the state of drawer. As long as i am  only reading values in the form by clicking on the button my initalValue updates. But if i update price and submit form for any 1 entry , then initial value my price or school doesn't change for other entries or schools. While my state is changing accordingly which I did check by rendering state. But my initialValue of form doesn't updating accordingly

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Table, Button, Popconfirm, Drawer, Form, Input, Select, notification } from 'antd'

const { Option } = Select

const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 10,
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 10,
  },
}
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: {
    offset: 7,
    span: 14,
  },
}


function SchoolRates({ form, relevantData }) {
  const [rates, setRates] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
   setRates(relevantData)
}, [someCondition])

  const updateRates = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    form.validateFields((error, values) => {
      console.log(error, values, 'forms')
    })
    return 'Data Updated'
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {`${rates?.schoolName}, ${rates?.Price}`}
      </div>
      <Form {...layout} initialValue={rates} onSubmit={e => updateRates(e)}>
        <Form.Item label="Country" style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }} size="small">
          {form.getFieldDecorator('schoolName', {
            initialValue: rates?.schoolname,
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please select a school!' }],
          })(
            <Select
              placeholder="School"
              allowClear
              size="small"
              style={{ borderRadius: 0 }}
            >
              {schoolList.map(item => (
                <Option value={item}>{item}</Option>
              ))}
            </Select>,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label="Price / Learner" style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }} size="small">
          {form.getFieldDecorator('price', {
            initialValue: rates?.price,
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter price/learner' }],
          })(
            <Input
              size="small"
              type="number"
              style={{ borderRadius: 0 }}
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" size="small">
            Save
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}

export default Form.create()(UpdateRates)
```

I just want to re render the complete form to update data as soon as I click on other school from my table

Answer (score 7):

To update initialValue form  input fields need to be cleaned or reset.
So add form.resetFields()(to reset data in input fields) after successful submission of form.

Comment: I added `form.resetFields()` in `useEffect` with dependancy as the state variable and it worked for me

Comment: could you explain with more detail code with your answer?